# Using useContext showing an error: Undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I am attempting to write a sign in screen within React-Native, but I got the error following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxRcx.jpg)

my SignInScreen code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { 
    View, 
    Text, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    TextInput,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet ,
    StatusBar,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';

import { AuthContext } from '../components/context';

import Users from '../model/users';

const SignInScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
        check_textInputChange: false,
        secureTextEntry: true,
        isValidUser: true,
        isValidPassword: true,
    });

    const { colors } = useTheme();

    const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

    const textInputChange = (val) => {
        if( val.trim().length >= 4 ) {
            setData({
                ...data,
                username: val,
                check_textInputChange: true,
                isValidUser: true
            });
        } else {
            setData({
                ...data,
                username: val,
                check_textInputChange: false,
                isValidUser: false
            });
        }
    }
```

my context.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

my app.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignInScreen from "./screens/SignInScreen";


export default function App() {
  return <SignInScreen/>;
}
```

I am just wondering is it missing some components and how do I fix it? And I already tried to reinstall my packages.

Comment: Have you added a provider for your context somewhere?

Comment: above are my entire code, I am just starting to learn React-Native, I actually have no idea what provider is

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `signIn` function to the context somewhere. Typically, this is achieved with a context provider. You can find some more information in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider). It may look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignInScreen from "./screens/SignInScreen";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const signIn = () => {
  // ... sign into an account or something
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{signIn}}>
        <SignInScreen/>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

However, it may be worth reading through the docs and considering why you are using context here as this is not often how a sign-in function works in React/React-Native.